# CSS : apply transform before animation

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying to animate my infinite slider when pressing next and prev button. The animation triggers before my images transform property is taken into account. How can we make the transform trigger first ? I tried setting the animation in a specific class and apply it after transform. I also tried putting animation in CSS then in JS but it leads to the same result : images make their translation, then the transform triggers

thanks for your help

```js
//Img Src Array
imageArray = [
  "https://www.referenseo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/image-attractive-960x540.jpg",
  "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664474619075-644dd191935f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80",
  "https://99designs-blog.imgix.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/web-images.jpg?auto=format&q=60&w=1600&h=824&fit=crop&crop=faces",
  "https://cdn.futura-sciences.com/sources/images/dossier/773/01-intro-773.jpg",
  "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/3j5RylRv1ZdswxcBaMi0y7/b84fa97296bd2350db6ea194c0dce7db/Music_Icon.jpg",
  "https://imgv3.fotor.com/images/blog-cover-image/part-blurry-image.jpg"
];


const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-image");
const sliderPage = document.getElementById("slider-page");

let slideOnEachSide = 2;
let scrollAmountVW = (2 * slideOnEachSide + 1) / 100;
let currentSlideIndex = slideOnEachSide + 1;
let lastSlideIndex = slides.length / 2;

// Remove all children : reset the slider with new array each iteration 
function removeAllChildNodes(parent) {
  while (parent.firstChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
  }
}


function displayImages() {
    removeAllChildNodes(slider);
  for (let i = 0; i < 2 * slideOnEachSide + 1; i++) {
    var imgFromArray = document.createElement("img");
    imgFromArray.src = imageArray[i];
    imgFromArray.classList.add("slider-image");
    imgFromArray.style.margin = `${scrollAmountVW}vw`;
    imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3)";
    imgFromArray.style.animation = "imageSlideRight 3s linear";
    imgFromArray.style.display = "inline-block";
    slider.appendChild(imgFromArray);
    if (i === slideOnEachSide) {
      imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(1)";
    } else {
      if (i - slideOnEachSide === -1 || i - slideOnEachSide === 1) {
        imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.6)";
      } else {
        imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3)";
      }
    }
  }
}

displayImages();

// Button sliding logic
let nextbutton = document.querySelector(".next");
let prevbutton = document.querySelector(".prev");

nextbutton.onclick = () => {
  imageArray.push(imageArray.shift());
  displayImages();
};

prevbutton.onclick = () => {
  imageArray.unshift(imageArray.pop());
  displayImages();
};
```

```css
/* CSS Reset */
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.slider-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow:hidden
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-image {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;
  animation: imageSlideRight 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: tranform 0.3s ease-in-out, scale 0.3s ease-in-out;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 33vw;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  display: none;
}


/* CSS Buttons
 */

.button-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 20vw;
  z-index: 3;
}

.next,
.prev {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Slide animation */

@keyframes imageSlideRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(20vw);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-page">
  <div class="slider-container" id="slider-container">
    <div class="slider" id="slider">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't really understand what is the behaviour you are looking for. What should happen when you don't do anything? What should happen when you click the next/prev buttons?

Comment: Please, provide a Fiddle to help us to help you )

Comment: @atteggiani i want the slider to display images on three diferent sizes based on their position on the page. When i click prev or next buttons i want images to move accordingly with a smooth translating and scaling animation.

I initially made the whole slider movce with translateX() which worked like a charm until i had to reset the animation and the translateX(${currentValue+20}vw) usually passed suddenly had to become translateX(0) for instance. 

I decided to try another road where the slider display 5 first images of an array and the next and prev button makes the array shift items

Comment: @VincentDecaux ,Fiddle dee, Fiddle done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that both translate and scale are values for the transform property. You need to treat them as 1 value and make it work with either transition or animation.
I got them to work at the same time by doing the following:

1. Remove the animation.
2. Change `transition: tranform 0.3s ease-in-out, scale 0.3s ease-in-out;` to `transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;`. Be sure to fix the typo in tranSform.
3. Change:
   `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3)";` -> `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3) translateX(20vw)";`
   `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(1)";` -> `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(1) translateX(0)";`
   `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.6)";` -> `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.6) translateX(0)";`
   `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3)";` -> `imgFromArray.style.transform = "scale(0.3) translateX(0)";`
4. Add `slider.offsetHeight;` below `slider.appendChild(imgFromArray);`. This will make the browser put the image element in the page first. Then afterwards, the transform properties are changed by JS and the transition kicks in.

Comment: Thank you, I went down the " imgFromArray.style.animation = "imageSlideRightMid 0.3s ease-in forwards" road and it worked :)